# Switch on/off using jquery show() and hide()

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to get this to work, to make the effect of an off/on switch, how to best get this result? is any method better than the other? toggle? or something else.

I tried to add a snippet here, but unfortunately the image is not showing... I have my code on git, if you care to look...
http://lucky500.github.io/challenge5/

I understand that might css might not be right as well, I believe both images should occupy the same space, and one of the images should be set to display: none... but I can't get it to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log("Hello from jQuery!");
$('.switch').on('click', function(){
 $('.night').hide();
 $('.day').show;
})
$('.switch').on('click', function(){
 $('.night').show();
 $('.day').hide();
});

});
```

```css
.switch {
 z-index: 1;
 float: right;
}

.day {
 display: none;
 background: url(http://imgur.com/KsK0GCt);
}

.night {
 background: url(http://imgur.com/os0mgek);
}

.night, .day {
 height: 332px;
 width: 225px;
 float: right;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch">
  <div class="day"></div>
  <div class="night"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `$('#selector').toggle()` or do something like `if $('#selector').hasClass('day') { $('#selector').removeClass('day'); $('#selector').addClass('night'); }else{ $('#selector').removeClass('night'); $('#selector').addClass('day');`

Comment: You should only have one click function not two? And your also missing the parthesis part of the show method in your first switch method $('.day').show; should be $('.day').show();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/suyaxa/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.switch').on('click', function(){
    $('.night, .day').toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
.switch {
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
}
.day {
  display: none;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/KsK0GCt.png);
}
.night {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/os0mgek.png);
}
.night, .day {
  height: 332px;
  width: 225px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="switch">
  <div class="day"></div>
  <div class="night"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that easy... Thanks Roko...that did it...I am going to accept your answer as soon as I can. Thanks again